# Wanting to use the data I get back when using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to get a JSON response. I am getting is as a PhotoPXArray (model I created using mantle). The log output is exactly the data I want. My problem is using the data. How do I go about saving the response data as a variable that can be used elsewhere in my program.

Also, I am using Sculptor to help with serializing.

```
-(NSArray*) getPhotoForWord:(NSString*)word {
    NSArray *results = nil;

    NSString *requestString = BASE_URL;
    requestString = [requestString stringByAppendingString:@"photos/search?term="];
    requestString = [requestString stringByAppendingString:word];
    requestString = [requestString stringByAppendingString:CONSUMER_KEY];



    NSString *encoded = [requestString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [SCLMantleResponseSerializer serializerForModelClass:PhotoPXArray.class];
    [manager GET:encoded
      parameters:nil
         //success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, PhotoPXArray *responseObject) {
             NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);


         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }];


    return results;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the Apple documentation regarding [blocks and variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html). Or you can view this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030873/always-pass-weak-reference-of-self-into-block-in-arc) on SO that will probably also answer your question.

From the Apple docs:

> __block variables live in storage that is shared between the lexical scope of the variable and all blocks and block copies declared or
>   created within the variable’s lexical scope. Thus, the storage will
>   survive the destruction of the stack frame if any copies of the blocks
>   declared within the frame survive beyond the end of the frame (for
>   example, by being enqueued somewhere for later execution). Multiple
>   blocks in a given lexical scope can simultaneously use a shared
>   variable.

Comment: Thank you! I tried _block with 1 underscore. I didn't notice the second one until now.

Comment: Even marked as `__block`, this array will be returned immediately and be empty, not having time for the request to complete. This is not the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a completion block to get your data out:

```objc
- (void)getPhotoForWord:(NSString *)word completionHandler:(void ^(PhotoPXArray *photoArray))completionHandler
{
    NSString *requestString = BASE_URL;
    requestString = [requestString stringByAppendingString:@"photos/search?term="];
    requestString = [requestString stringByAppendingString:word];
    requestString = [requestString stringByAppendingString:CONSUMER_KEY];

    NSString *encoded = [requestString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [SCLMantleResponseSerializer serializerForModelClass:PhotoPXArray.class];
    [manager GET:encoded
      parameters:nil
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, PhotoPXArray *responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
            if (completionHandler) {
                completionHandler(responseObject);
            }
      } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
[object getPhotoForWord:@"word" completionHandler:^(PhotoPXArray *photoArray) {
    // Do something with photo array.
}];
```

Note that this call is asynchronous and will complete at some unknown time in the future. Also, you should likely take an `NSError` argument in the completion block so you can see if you get an error from the request, but I'll leave that to you.