# presentViewController with delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

Calling `[self presentViewController]` on an instance of `UIAlertController` loads the alert immediately. Is there a way to delay its presentation?

```
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Do you mean UIAlertController? Or UIAlertView? And do you mean the presentation of the alert or presentation of another viewController from an action within the alert?

Comment: @JimTierney I mean UIAlertController. Did you down vote me?

Comment: no downvote from me. Glad you got it sorted though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use GCD or `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

You can also create a local variable and then call present at the right time that you want. Depends on your use-case, one of these three should help you on delaying and showing the alert controller at the right moment.

EDIT: Here's the Swift version of this answer:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

You can also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139219/how-do-you-trigger-a-block-after-a-delay-like-performselectorwithobjectafter)

Comment: The `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` doesn't work at all. GCD works but the alert from the UIAlertController is not appearing in the app. Is it because the alert should be called on the main thread?

Comment: Yes it should be called from the Main Thread otherwise you leave yourself open to weird / undefined behavior

Comment: Yeah, make sure that your code is running on the main thread. I updated the code

Comment: Does it make sense to encapsulate a call to an instance of a UIAlertController within GCD?

Comment: Yeah, you should be good depends on your reference type to the `UIViewController`. You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030873/always-pass-weak-reference-of-self-into-block-in-arc for in-detail of blocks and ARC

Comment: Congratulations! You provide an excellent answer to my question. May everyone upvote the question and @manman's answer!

Comment: Great, glad it helped on your issue.

Comment: Thanks once again . . . Do you know how to fine tune the delay? How can I change `(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)` to speed things up just a little bit?

Comment: instead of 1, you should put the number of seconds that you want the delay.

Comment: The call to `dispatch_async` is pointless here. As written, the call to `dispatch_after` already ensures its block is called on the main thread.

Comment: @rmaddy Without `dispatch_async` the UIAlert is not called. Which should I use `dispatch_after` or `dispatch_async`?

Comment: If I want a value less than 1, is there a way to manipulate `(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)`?

Comment: @Eric If you want a delay, you just need `dispatch_after`.

Comment: @Eric Change the `1` to `0.5` or whatever amount you need. It's a float value in seconds.

Comment: @maddy yeah you're right, I removed that part from the sample code. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: It crashed with `0.5.` In any case it is working wonderfully following @rmaddy's comments to remove the `dispatch_async`. Thanks, @rmaddy. @manman Can you upvote the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you are waiting for something to download or something, you may also consider using a block that is called (and presents the view controller) once the task is complete. If you do this you should also use some sort of loading animation.

Comment: Thanks, @Raesu. I am not waiting for anything to download. The key is to display an alert updating a user's coin purse with coins earned from an offer wall. The callback is lightening fast so there is no need to wait, unless, of course, there is something missing.

Comment: Got it. In @manman's answer I actually prefer the `performSelector:...afterDelay:` method, cleaner code.

Comment: Must selectors be either methods, functions, or actions, right? Alert is an instance of the class UIAlertViewController.  Can I call an ivar as a selector?

Comment: I believe they have to be methods. I just make a method to execute that code, then use `performSelector:...afterDelay:` to call it. No GCD spaghetti code!

Comment: If `performSelector:afterDelay:` requires a method, then I understand now why @manman's solution with GCD works in lieu of the remaining two! Thanks for the explanation!