# Objective-C ARC block __strong __weak

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, block

With ARC

test1:

```
@interface test01ViewController ()

@property (strong) void(^myBlock)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL stop);

@end

@implementation test01ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.navigationItem.title = @"test01";

    [self setMyBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL stop) {
        [self doSomethingWithObj:obj];
    }];
}
```

object (`self`) has an explicit strong reference to the block. And the block has an implicit `strong` reference to `self`. That's a cycle, and now neither object will be deallocated properly.

so test1 `dealloc` not calling.

test2:

```
@interface test03ViewController ()

@property (strong) void(^myBlock)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL stop);

@end

@implementation test03ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.navigationItem.title = @"test03";

    __weak test03ViewController *weakSelf = self;
    [self setMyBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL stop) {
        __strong test03ViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;
        [strongSelf doSomethingWithObj:obj];
    }];
}
```

__weakSelf - > __strongSelf, I think it not difference with `test1` , but test2 can calling `dealloc`.

Why?

Comment: in test 2: while myBlock will not be executed it will not retain self

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28475562/543224

> Anyway regarding this pattern, capturing a strong reference there doesn't do anything for the case of self getting deallocated before the block runs, that can still happen. It does ensure self doesn't get deallocated while executing the block. This matters if the block does async operations itself giving a window for that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the block captures the variable `self`, which is a strong reference (i.e. it has type `test01ViewController * __strong`).

In the second case, the block captures the variable `weakSelf`, which is a weak reference (i.e. it has type `test03ViewController * __weak`).