# Why cannot I modify an object inside my method

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

I am calling an Api asynchronously to get the data. Then I am assigning the data to a shared instance successfully inside a block given below.

```
RestApiManager *api= [[RestApiManager alloc]init];
[ObjectBuilder sharedManager];

self.obj = [[Object alloc]init];
[api get_data:credential.password finish:^(NSDictionary *data) {

    if(data){
       self.obj = [ObjectBuilder obj:data];
        [[ObjectBuilder sharedManager]setObject:self.obj];

    }
```

This all working as expected except when I try to update some of the values in one of NSMutableDictionary properties of the obj.

```
- (void)update: (NSInteger) temp {

   array3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   NSNumber *start =[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:var];
   [NSNumber numberWithInteger:var2];
   NSNumber *temp2 =[NSNumber numberWithInteger:temp];
   [array3 addObject:temp2];
   [array3 addObject:start];
   [array3 addObject:end];
   [self.obj.sch setObject:array3 forKey:temp2];

}
```

> [obj.sch setObject:array3 forKey:temp2]; always crashes my app.

Now I have vague idea whats going on, basically I am setting obj inside a block code, whilst in my update function I am trying to change the contents outside block code.

The error I get is

> reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Note this error goes away if i declare line

> [[ObjectBuilder sharedManager]setObject:obj];

Outside the finish:^ block
But then I lose all the data obtained from api call.

Object is declared as below `@interface Object : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic)  NSMutableDictionary *sch;`

Comment: And what's the error message? What I don't understand is what is `obj` on that line? Because in the code before, it's a local var.

Comment: @Larme I updated the code, and error I am getting and also added the line which explains when the error disappears, but I lose the data.

Comment: `__NSDictionaryI` means `NSImmutableDictionary` (that's why there is an uppercase "i" at the end), in other words, a `NSDictionary`, not a `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: I have added the declaration of sch in Object model. Its declared as mutabledictionary. But odd thing is why this error only appears when sharedManager is declared inside the block.

Comment: Declaring and setting is different. For instance if you do `sch = someDictionaryImmutable`, you'll get the same issue.

Comment: so whats the fix here

Comment: `sch = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: someDictionaryImmutable];` instead?

Comment: NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setValue:array3 forKey:temp2];
[self.obj.sch setDictionary:dict]; This resulted in same error

Comment: `sch` is supposed to be a mutable dictionary. So assign it an `NSMutableDictionary`, not an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: @rmaddy this seem to work self.obj.sch = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:array3 forKey:temp2];  But I now face a newer issues, since I run this in a loop, where array3 gets new values on each iteration, I only get final values into my sch. ideally I like a way, it saves array3 and key and adds second array3 and key separately instead of overwriting

Comment: If you have a new issue, post a new question with clear and specific details. And you may as well delete this question.

Comment: Retain cycle ahead! Never reference `self` strongly inside of a block. It shouldn't crash your app though... `__block typeof(self) weakSelf = self` and then use `weakSelf.obj = `

Comment: Check this answer for more detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/20032131/1041122

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert it didn't work

Comment: Ok, let me check back later. But nevertheless, go read that reply I linked, it's really good info. I love working with blocks and fell for this trap for quite some time ;)

Comment: My comment wasn't actaually an attenpt to fix your issue, only additional information. Please follow rmaddys advice and create a new question for the new issue.