# Why Swift don't automatically handle memory leaks?

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, retain-cycle

When I started developing Swift code I wasn't that experienced handling memory leaks, so it take some time to me to figure out that what is a retain cycle, what is ARC, and why I should use `weak` or `unowned` inside my closures that was creating those retain cycles.

By default I always add this piece of code in closures that is referencing self:

```
class MyController: UIViewController {
    var myClosure: (Data?, Error?)?

    override viewDidLoad() {
        self.myClosure = { [weak self] (data, err) in 
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.present(someVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

That code is something very common and using this `weak` modifier and also unwrapping `self` is something that is almost a default code.

That makes me question. If I have to always add a `weak self` in code that is referencing `self` and not allowing the class to be deinit WHY Apple don't make it a default behaviour on the language so we don't need to have this code repeating everywhere on our code base?

Comment: The UX of this definitely still has some room for improvement, but fundamentally, automating this would require hardcoding into the compiler an assumption about what should happen when `self` is `nil`. In your case, you just no-op. That's probably the most common valid case, but I imagine there are others.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to always use `weak self` when referencing `self` in a closure.

But in this particular case you **do have to** and it was [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20032131/8990225)