# Memory Abandonment mainly due to VM: CoreAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, core-animation, abandoned-memory

I am making an app that has a lot of animations and nested animations.

```
self.countDownAnimationImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3" ofType:@"png"]]];

    if([self.deviceType isEqualToString:@"iphone"])
    {
        self.countDownAnimationImage.frame = CGRectMake(120, 200, 80, 120);
    }
    else if([self.deviceType isEqualToString:@"iphone5"])
    {
        self.countDownAnimationImage.frame = CGRectMake(120, 288, 80, 120);
    }

    [self.view addSubview:self.countDownAnimationImage];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.8
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         self.countDownAnimationImage.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.countDownAnimationImage.transform, 1.5, 1.5);

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                                               delay:0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                                          animations:^{
                                              self.countDownAnimationImage.alpha = 0;
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished)
                          {
                              self.countDownAnimationImage.alpha = 1;
                              self.countDownAnimationImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2" ofType:@"png"]];
                              self.countDownAnimationImage.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.countDownAnimationImage.transform, .66666667, .6666667);
                              [UIView animateWithDuration:.8
                                                    delay:0
                                                  options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                                               animations:^{
                                                self.countDownAnimationImage.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.countDownAnimationImage.transform, 1.5, 1.5);
                                                   self.countDownAnimationImage.alpha = 1;
                                               }
                                               completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                                   [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                                                                         delay:0
                                                                       options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                                                                    animations:^{

                                                                        self.countDownAnimationImage.alpha = 0;
                                                                    }
                                                                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                                                        self.countDownAnimationImage.alpha = 1;
                                                                        self.countDownAnimationImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"png"]];
                                                                        self.countDownAnimationImage.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.countDownAnimationImage.transform, .66666667, .6666667);
                                                                        [UIView animateWithDuration:.8
                                                                                              delay:0
                                                                                            options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                                                                                         animations:^{


                                                                                             self.countDownAnimationImage.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.countDownAnimationImage.transform, 1.5, 1.5);
                                                                                             self.countDownAnimationImage.alpha = 1;
                                                                                         }
                                                                                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                                                                             [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                                                                                                                   delay:0
                                                                                                                 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                                                                                                              animations:^{

                                                                                                                  self.countDownAnimationImage.alpha = 0;
                                                                                                              }
                                                                                                              completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                                                                                                  [self.countDownAnimationImage removeFromSuperview];


                                                                                                              }];

                                                                                         }];


                                                                    }];

                                               }];
                          }];

                     } ];
```

This is an example of a start animation that shows 3-2-1

I have more animations, but all are not as complex. I noticed that my app crashes on the ipad due to memory issues, and ran instruments.

It is not showing any leaks, but the allocation heap size is continuously increasing.  After a heapshot analysis, I noticed that most of the memory was being consumed by:

VM: CoreAnimation

VM: ImageIO_PNG_Data

I tried looking at the stack trace, and am unable to figure out where exactly am I generating this abandoned memory.

Another example of the kind of animation I am using:

```
    UIImageView *animationImage;
if([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height == 568)
{
    animationImage  = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(24, 250, 150, 80)];
}
else if([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height == 480)
{
    animationImage  = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(24, 200, 150, 80)];
}
else
{
    animationImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(184, 511, 218, 118)];
}

CGRect frame = animationImage.frame;
frame.size.height*=1.8;
frame.size.width*=1.8;
[animationImage setFrame:frame];


animationImage.image =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"]];

animationImage.alpha = 0;
[self.view addSubview:animationImage];
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{

                     animationImage.alpha=1;

                     [animationImage setFrame:frame];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
                                           delay:.6
                                         options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                                      animations:^{
                                          animationImage.alpha=0;
                                          CGRect frame = animationImage.frame;
                                          if([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height > 568)
                                          {
                                              frame.origin.y-=210;
                                          }
                                          else
                                          {
                                              frame.origin.y-=90;
                                          }
                                          [animationImage setFrame:frame];
                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                          [animationImage removeFromSuperview];

                                      }];
                 }];
```

Comment: Is it possible that animation is being repeatedly added to the same view?  Perhaps don't animate if `self.countDownAnimationImage != nil`?

Comment: the animation code is called in viewdidload, and runs once. 
The abandoned memory was created when I popped the VC, because the VM: Coreanimation heap allocation was not released. 
Thus, whenever I created a new instance of the VC it was allocating new memory.

Comment: OK, so we might be looking at a retain cycle.  How about trying the Ye Olde `weakSelf` solution?

Comment: I am not aware of the weakself solution. Please let me know more about it, thanks!!

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194613/is-it-necessary-to-use-weak-references-to-self-always-inside-blocks