# Is it necessary to use __block when setting a BOOL flag in a completion block?

Tags: objective-c, block, objective-c-blocks

I'm using the following code:

```
 [_presenter presentViewController:_alert animated:YES completion:^{
               _isShowingAlert = YES;
            }];
```

Do I need to use the __block qualifier for this flag? I tried it without and it seems to work (sets the BOOL so the change is visible outside the block) and I'm not clear why it works.

BOOL is declared at the top of .m thus:

```
@implementation NotificationTracking {
    BOOL _isShowingAlert;
}
```

Comment: odd that the question is about a bool flag but the posted code contains no declaration or usage of the flag

Comment: Question updated, hope that helps clarify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instance variables, including ones declared in `@implementation` and in class extensions, never need the `__block` modifier. It is necessary only for local variables, which are otherwise captured by value in Objective-C blocks.

What happens here is that the modification is done through the implicitly captured `self` variable. Even though the variable `self` is captured by value, it provides a reference to all instance variables of the class, allowing the block to make changes.

Comment: Ok thanks, do I need to use weakSelf in this case to avoid retain cycle or anything like that?

Comment: @BradThomas Not necessarily: the answer on weak self depends on the usage of the block: if you must store the block in an instance variable inside `self`, you need a weak reference; otherwise, you don't. Here is a related [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13194818/335858) on `weakSelf`.

Answer (score 5):

You need the `__block` qualifier when updating a local variable. If you're updating a class property (or, in your case, an instance variable), the `__block` qualifier is not needed.

With an asynchronous block, updating local variables doesn't generally make sense, so you won't often see it in this context.